# C: Fixed length array that dumps oldest, shifts and adds newest

Tags: c, arrays, queue

I want a structure that is part array and part fixed-size queue: i would like to be able to append a number to one end, while the number on the opposite side gets dumped. All the while i'd like to always be able to say a[i] or similar and get the value at that index (just peeking, no popping!).

So the progress should look like this:

```
a={2,3,4} | append a 5
a={3,4,5} | append a 99 
a={4,5,99}| now ask for a[1], get 5
```

etc. Is there some **built-in** in C that does that or sth. similar?

EDIT2: Currently i am running with something like this, which is obviously quite dependent on the implementation providing that the unsigned char operation 255+=1 evaluates to 0:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

unsigned char p =0;   //  helper that provides the current tail of queue
int a[1 << CHAR_BIT]; // array of size 2^[bit-size of helper]

int from_a(unsigned char i) {
    return a[(i+p)];  // addition of helper makes i the true index
}

void append_to_a(int x) {
    a[0]=x;
    p+=1; // rolling-over of unsigned char provides circularity
}
```

Just out of interest, not part of the main question: is there a another language that has this?

EDIT:

The process should be automatic (no need to do append.. and then pop/delete/shift..)  no write access to existing members is needed (just read, but indexed).

Thanks to everyone answering that there is no built-in in C and offering alternatives. I implemented something weird, but deque, circular queue/-buffer,  and container were valuable search terms.

'Thanks' to everyone assuring me that in any turing-complete environment this is possible somehow - i would have despaired otherwise (my question was about built-ins but the knowledge that universal computers can indeed compute is quite soothing).

Comment: "Is there some built-in in C that does that" - No, but it's easy to write your own code that does that

Comment: " is there a another language that has this" - C++ has container types that make it very easy to do that

Comment: Write a doubly linked list or switch to C++ and use `std::list` or `std::deque`

Comment: Think you can look into `memmove` and implement the shifting yourself if you really want to.

Comment: Are you *sure* you want to have that? There is a thing called [ring buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer), but you don't *move* anything in it.

Comment: As for "which programming language can do this": *every Turing-complete programming language can do the same things"

Comment: @AnttiHaapala As for "As for "which programming language can do this": " - i did not want to know that, i wanted to know about built-ins; thanks for the ring buffer, anyways!

Comment: An array and `memmove` can do just what you are asking. With the array full, `memmove (array, &array[1], sizeof array - sizeof *array);` now add the new element at the end.  (but the ring-buffer will be more efficient)

Answer (score 1):

> i would like to be able to append a number to the right (or left)
>   while the oldest number gets dumped. So the progress should look like
>   this: [2,3,4], [3,4,5], [4,5,6], etc. Is there some built-in in C that
>   does that?

No, you have to implement your own data-structure.

> is there a another language that has this?

You could perform such operation using Deque easily. In c++ (STL) or Java(in collection framework) has its implementation.Deque can be implemented in python using the module `'collections'`.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation of absence in C; but you know of no language that does this built-in?

Comment: @bukwyrm like I said in my answer c++, java and python provide the implementation for these type of data structure. So basically you don't need to implement it by yourself.

Comment: i looked into the c++ deque - it does not allow for automatic discard of old members if new members come in. the Python one does, though. thanks for that!

Comment: @bukwyrm well you need to modify the behavior as per your needs depending on the language you're using.

Answer (score 1):

C doesn't have any such built-in. But with C++ container `deque`, you can do this easily.

A minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

int main()
{
    // Create a deque containing integers
    std::deque<int> d = {1, 2, 3};
    int sizeLimit = 3;
    if(d.size() == sizeLimit)
    {
        d.pop_front(); //remove from front
    }
    d.push_back(4); //add at the end

    // Iterate and print values of deque
    for(int n : d) {
        std::cout << n << '\n';
    }
}
```

Python does have `collections.deque` in its standard library which has this functionality.

```
import collections
d = collections.deque(maxlen=3)
print(d)

for i in range(3):
  d.append(i)

print(d)

d.append(3)
print(d)

d.append(4)
print(d)
```

You can see live demo [here](https://repl.it/repls/DisastrousFirebrickForce).

Comment: thanks for the confirmation of absence in C; but you know of no language that does this built-in?

Comment: I am only familiar with a few. Fortran, C, C++. Python. Perl. Delphi, Java. Not in these languages.

Comment: Yes, just checked that up right now. Was about to comment. :)

Comment: Interestingly, this deque recipe seems to be implemented in C. https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#deque-recipes

Comment: The collections.deque from Python is the capability i was looking for: new members to the left automatically kick old members out to the right. Thanks!

Comment: i looked into the c++ deque - it does not allow for automatic discard of old members if new members come in.

Comment: @bukwyrm:  yeah, not auto discard in C++. We have to pop manually. Do you want me to put the python example instead in the answer?

Comment: Yes, please. I also learned just now that Java has a LinkedHashMap class that does that (after overriding removeEldest), and com.google.common.collect
Class EvictingQueue might also be what i asked for.

Comment: though i don't know if i can look at any part of the queue (i'd want to) or just peek at the head of the queue.

Comment: @bukwyrm: Added the python example too. You can accepted this answer if you are satisfied.